# tvOS - Custom TextField

Tags: swift, tvos

I am currently working on tvOS app and I am stuck at subclassing textfields. I normally subclass textfields on iOS without problem, somehow tvOS is different.
Here are the bugs that are happening:

- textColor is white, after pressing and typing textColor is black
- attributed placeholder is white, after typing text, text is black and after clearing text, placeholder appears black and centered horizontally
- secure text entry enlarges font
- and another random bugs appear and overall textfield is buggy

(It happens even if subclass is very basic - like changed text color after init or in setup method etc.)

Do you have any idea how to fix it or working solution of textfield subclass on tvOS? **Thanks**